# Text not centering with Boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The below should be centering with the text-center class but it is not. How do I align the heading and p tags center. Thank you. I'm trying to do it using bootstrap.

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h2>Test Heading</h2>
        <p>some test text</p>
    </div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
```

Comment: Please check your CDN , Code is all correct, Or make a fiddle.

Comment: Actually it is centered: https://jsfiddle.net/hxacfxyk/

Comment: It is working fine, there might be some conflict with other css in your project. see it here - https://jsfiddle.net/bqvnp6Lb/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code works fine.
You may check your bootstrap link or CDN.

Visit This Link
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h

Here you find same example.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my system is not pulling in the CDN or local bootstrap file. Tested it in codepen and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
  padding:5%;
  background-color:#000;
  height:400px;
  width:450px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main text-center">
    <h2>This is the text</h2>
    <h4>This is description text</h4>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Here is simple thing i have done. Check out working snippet.

Greetings!